# filtering browser history on selected tab

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, safari, history, tabbed-browsing

Using tabbed browsing you may end up with some tabs having been opened a while ago, your history though has moved forward, let's say days or even a month.
Now you want to refer at what stage of the history the tab was opened, maybe you want to go back.

**is there a way to "filter" history basing it only on the current selected tab?**